# Joomla 3: No more Write permissions

Tags: joomla, permissions, file-permissions, joomla3.0, folder-permissions

I have a Joomla 3 Installation on which I had full rights within in the Joomla Backend, i. e. I could upload files or change settings. Today I tried to delete a file, which was not possible any more: The system told me, that 1.) deleting failed, and 2.) deleting was successfull (the file was still there).

I also noticed that I am not able to do anything that requires writing permission, like clearing the cache or uploading a new file.

In "System Information", Joomla tells me, that every folder is writing protected, including "media".

What do you think are possible causes for this problem? Is it on the Joomla or the Server side?

*Additional Information: The site was not created by me and is hosted on a server owned (or rented) by another web designer, so I don't have full access to the server.*

**System Information:**
Linux fred 2.6.32-23-pve
PHP 5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Joomla! 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Well at those conditions it seems a Server side issue.
Like someone changed the permissions on the server.

Ask the owner of the server to check the permissions and update if necessary.